# Basic page routing using pager.js and Knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, pagerjs

I am trying to setup a very basic page-routing system inside of a pre-existing knockout application.  I have added all dependencies and am running:

```
pager.extendWithPage(masterViewModel.goToObjectives);

// Apply the KO bindings
ko.applyBindings(masterViewModel);

pager.start();
```

But when I add the page Id to my 'Objetives' template via:

```
data-bind="page: {id: 'outcomes'}, with: $root.objectivesVM()"
```

I am getting an error in the console of:

```
knockout-debug.js:3326 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "page: function (){return {id:'outcomes'} }"
Message: Cannot read property 'children' of null
```

I have tried adding the page Id elsewhere but I get this error no matter what.  Anyone have experience with this and know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you need to put the `with` inside the `page` binding?
`data-bind="page: {id: 'outcomes', with: $root.objectivesVM}"`

Comment: @Adrian...That's what I thought, too.  But moving it there gives me the same error.